# How to bind drop down based on selected text

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list as follows:

```
<select name="ddTblrule" id="ddTblrule" class="controlFont controlWidth">
    <option value="Abc">Abc [ abc ]</option>
    <option value="Abc">Abc [ abc1 ]</option>
    <option value="Abc">Abc [ abc2 ]</option>
    <option value="Abc Associations">abc Associations [ abcas ]</option>
</select>
```

Since the values of drop down are the same (It should be same, as values are depended on other textbox). I have a grid which contains the selected drop  down text in it. when user clicks on edit button I have to show the respective text selected in drop down for which I am using the following code.

```
 var ruleObj = data.find('td:eq(3)').text();
 $("#ddTblrule option").removeAttr("selected");
 $("#ddTblrule option").filter(function () {
     return this.text == ruleObj;
 }).attr('selected', true);
```

But the data is not displaying properly in drop down. Please help

Comment: add a jsfiddle if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your question I think you are looking for something like following.

```js
$('#edit').click(function() {
    var ruleObj = 'Abc [ abc2 ]';
    $("#ddTblrule option").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == ruleObj;
    }).prop('selected', true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="ddTblrule" id="ddTblrule" class="controlFont controlWidth">
    <option value="Abc">Abc [ abc ]</option>
    <option value="Abc">Abc [ abc1 ]</option>
    <option value="Abc">Abc [ abc2 ]</option>
    <option value="Abc Associations">abc Associations [ abcas ]</option>
</select>

<button id="edit">Edit</button>
```

Comment: it worked. Now, in other case, I have ruleObj as '[abc]', how to check if the drop down contains this text and populate that value as selected text.

Comment: Working in IE 11 for me. Which version of IE are you using? @psobhan

Comment: There is a scenario where, i have value [abc] and need to check if the drop down text (Abc [abc]) contains the selected text [abc]. Code given below is not working in IE 11. 
$("#ddTblrule option").removeAttr("selected");
            $("#ddTblrule option").filter(function () {
                return $(this).text().toString().toLowerCase().includes('[ ' + alias.toString().toLowerCase() + ' ]');
            }).prop('selected', true);

Comment: This is not what I've suggested. @psobhan

Comment: I agree.The code mentioned as answer works just fine. I have been using drop down in multiple pages. One of the scenario was to display data based on the text it contains " $(this).text().toString().toLowerCase().includes('[ ' + alias.toString().toLowerCase() + ' ]'); }).prop('selected', true); " which is not working in IE 11 but works in firefox. Please help. @Azim

Comment: I don't find method  named `includes()`. How your code working in firefox !!??
You can use `indexOf()` instead. See https://jsfiddle.net/3cahbjoj/1/ @psobhan